# Background color of pseudo-element not working on Firefox

Tags: css, background-color, opacity, pseudo-element

I am testing a site I am working on, and find that the background-color of my footer pseudo-element is missing on Firefox. On Chrome it works fine.

The element itself is a wrapper around my content, with opacity set to 0.5. It makes use of background-color, ::before, and opacity. The point of this is to have a faded background for my footer, behind which you can see the page's background image.

[The site is](https://witchcraftandvagrancy.com/html/about.html).

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="footer">
          <p>Contact: email<wbr>@gmail.com</p>
          <div>
            <a href=facebook.com>facebook.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: black !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(1.3rem + 0.5vw);
  color: whitesmoke;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I am expecting a semi-transparent black background behind my footer content. I have set it up the way I have so that the foreground content is not transparent.

I have checked and cannot find any browser compatibility issues for background-color, ::before or opacity. I also cannot find any Firefox specific -moz- properties.

I am loading my page in a newly installed (and up to date) Firefox. I only browse in Private Mode and my cookies and cache are cleared every time I close the browser. I have also noticed this as an issue from the moment my site when live. This has been tested on mobile and laptop browsers.

Comment: That's because you using `& nesting selector` Firefox doesn't have support for it yet. [See Here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_nesting)

Comment: Thank you, I had checked for browser compatibility for everything but that! I have rewritten my code now.